# Vendor is not recognized or extend command

Tags: error, vendor

I am trying to run to test but every time I run a command that is related to the **vendor** folder, it shows the following error `'vendor' is not recognized or extend command operable program or batch file in Magento`

I do not know what I must do in the next step

Has anyone can help me a hand, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I Understand, you may try these things

> Install dependencies via composer

```
composer update
```

> Run test

In linux

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

In Windows

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I already run that command line but it does not work for me. When I run this command line `vendor/bin/mftf generate: test ` is still show me that error `vendor' is not recognized or extend command operable program or batch file in Magento`

Comment: You should try this `vendor\bin\phpunit` in your command line Interface if you are using window check the screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/6jjkitmdVSGN. For linux you should use 'vendor/bin/phpunit'.

Comment: Run this command line in root magento2 not mftf, right?

Comment: I don't get the opportunity of experiencing mftf. `composer update` should be in root magento2 but you can test run regardless where you are standing

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Hasham, when I run vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests, it shows me that error:  in ModuleReSovlver.php line 444:

Could not retrieve API from Magento instance <403 Forbidden>

Comment: Hey @MuhammadHasham I tried the above command mentioned by you `vendor\bin\phpunit` n `vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests` as well but in both scenario it gives me an error that `vendor is not recognized` while I also update the composer can you please tell me what is the issue